# Raspberry PI measure POST request with JMeter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, heroku, jmeter, raspberry-pi

I have simple Java EE application for measure by JMeter. Application run on heroku. I write name and surname into textbox on JSP. These are send on server by POST request. Server saves person and return same page with update list of persons. This is functionality which I measure in JMeter. This is result graph:

[image: POST request 700x]

I know why Average grows. Because list of person is bigger with each next request. So sending data to client are bigger with each next request and responses are slowly. But why average grows until from approximately half of graph? List yet gain from start testing. I measure on Raspberry PI. On desktop average grows from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of what you're doing, the graph you are showing is typical for a scenario where initially you're not hitting any bottleneck in any of your systems (and the response time is flat) and then you're hitting *some* bottleneck (so the response time starts to grow.)